# Sending variable to php from Javascript, not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am trying to make images change on click to a value (a file name) collected from a text file with PHP. This is done by collecting the file as an array (`data`) and echoing the right item in the array with the help of a counter (`counter`). This counter is incremented on each click with Javascript, but I want to return this incremented variable to PHP, to be able to change the images. Is there a way to do this? This is my attempt so far, trying my hand at posting the variable (see full code further down):

```
<script>
var variableToSend = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
$.post('lan7_old.php', {variable: variableToSend});
</script>

<?php $counter = $_POST['variable'];
echo $counter; ?
```

I thought that it ought to work to post as the page is refreshed on image click, but maybe I am mistaken here. Or is anything else wrong with my code? The images shown are still the first ones from the text file, but this is only because I add integers to `counter` in the PHP `echo` - there is no value set to the PHP `counter` variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
// Saves counter variable although the page is refreshed
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('counter') === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('counter', JSON.stringify(0));
    }
    // Incrementing counter until next page is needed
    $("img").click(function(){
        var counter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
        if(counter < 60) {
            counter += 4;
            localStorage.setItem('counter', JSON.stringify(counter));
        }
        else {
            localStorage.setItem('counter', JSON.stringify(0));
            window.location.href = '8.php';
            return false;
        }
        $("#test").text(localStorage.getItem('counter')); //for testing

        // sending js variable to be obtained by PHP
        var variableToSend = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
        $.post('lan7_old.php', {variable: variableToSend});
    });
    $("#test").text(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
});
</script>

<div class="main">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Heading 2</p>
    <div id="test">hello</div>

    <?php $data = getData($subtest_nr);
    // retrieving counter variable
    $counter = $_POST['variable'];
    echo $counter; //for testing ?> 

    <form id="myform" method="post">
    <div class="four_images">
            <div class="flex-item">
                <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.11" id="alt1" class="hidden">
                <label for="alt1"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter+0]; ?>"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-item">
                <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.12" id="alt2" class="hidden">
                <label for="alt2"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter + 1]; ?>"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-item">
                <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.13" id="alt3" class="hidden">
                <label for="alt3"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter+2]; ?>"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-item">
                <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.14" id="alt4" class="hidden">
                <label for="alt4"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter+3]; ?>"></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Image Selection">
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you fully understood how server-client architectures work. PHP run on the server, which means that if it gets a request from your browser, it puts together a response, which is one huge string. The way PHP does this is by running the code between `<?php` and `?>`, and copy-pasting everything outside of those tags. Once PHP has put together the huge string, it sends it back to your browser, who tried to parse and display it, and run any JavaScript, if present. The important thing is that PHP and JavaScript don't run at the same time; PHP is long done when JS has its turn.

Comment: With that in mind, `$.post` is the wrong approach here, because it sends an AJAX request (i.e. opens your page again in the background and retrieves its contents - you didn't specify a callback function though, so you never see the result), so the variable gets posted to a _different_ instance of your PHP script when you want it to be available on the _same_ one. In order to be able to do that, you'll need to reload the page on every user interaction though. Another possibility would be to change the images with JavaScript however, which would work without a reload.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I guess it won't work with this kind of solution then. Thought it might not be the best way, but wanted to try anyway... Will try changing the images with Javascript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is only refreshed if counter reaches 60 or above (window.location.href = '8.php¨).

Php only renders server side, now you are doing a javascript post request but ignoring the response, so this doesn't do anything.

Either you need to make your php return a response which you by javascript use to update the page (the DOM tree), or you should reload the whole page with for example window.location.href = "index.php?counter=" + counter.